# User privileges handle for a download folder and forward to print queue automatically

Tags: c#, printing, windows-services, privileges

I need to develop an application using c# as follow.

1. Separate folder used for each domain user as their browser download location. This path should be fixed (user shouldn't able to change the path). Only System admin user can change settings.
2. The Download folder should access denied for users (read/write/copy/paste/share)
3. When the file (image/PDF) downloaded to the folder, It should redirect to Print queue and after the print file, It should be delete.

To achieve these task, I am planning to use windows service for the task 2 and task 3.
For task 2, I am using below codes:

```
DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\FileDB\");

DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
            string User = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + combo_select_user.SelectedItem.ToString();

myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.Read,InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Deny));

myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```

But, When denying access for the user, It is stopped downloading any file to given directory. I need to handle this problem. which type of application or method that I can use for my purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by "browser download location"?  How is the user supposed to put files into this directory?

Comment: Browser settings can specify a location to download files. If we can disable  browser settings for some user, then automatically file will direct to specified location.

Comment: The browser runs in the user's context.  As far as the operating system is concerned, it *is* the user.  So "browser download location" and "access denied for users" are mutually contradictory requirements.  (You might be able to do it with a file system filter driver or something complicated like that, but you can't do it with permissions.)

Comment: Ok.. Thank you so much for your advice.